# Ошибка компилятора E2037 Declaration of '%s' differs from previous declaration

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

Компилятор выдаёт ошибку **E2037 Declaration of '%s' differs from previous declaration** тогда, когда описание метода, функции или процедуры в разделе `implementation` отличается от объявления в разделе `interface`. Поэтому обычный совет задающим этот вопрос на форумах - копировать объявление и вставлять, либо для методов класса использовать Auto Declaration (Ctrl+Shift+C по умолчанию). Всегда считал, что подобная ошибка - простая невнимательность.

Однако, сам столкнулся с этой ошибкой именно после Auto Declaration. Код:

```
type
  TAgarozeGel = class
  <...>
  public
  <...>
    procedure HorizontalReflection(Bitmap: TBitmap);
  end;

implementation

procedure TAgarozeGel.HorizontalReflection(Bitmap: TBitmap);
begin
 <...>
end;
```

компилируется именно с этой ошибкой, хотя IDE сам создавал описание метода в разделе implementation. Почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Протормозив 5 минут, которые потратил на изменение имени метода, всевозможные копирования и прочее, сообразил, что надо копать глубже и смотреть весь код, а не только код класса. Итак:

```
interface

Uses Vcl.Graphics;

type
  TAgarozeGel = class
  <...>
  public
  <...>
    procedure HorizontalReflection(Bitmap: TBitmap);
  end;

implementation

Uses ExtendedMath, System.Math, Winapi.Windows ;

procedure TAgarozeGel.HorizontalReflection(Bitmap: TBitmap);
begin
 <...>
end;
```

Сработала старая привычка избегать кросс-референс и ссылаться в разделе `interface` только на те модули, которые нужны для объявления типов. Как указал в комментариях @zed, повторно встречающиеся типы переопределяются по мере подключения модулей, в которых они описаны. И выходит, что `TBitmap` в объявлении метода - из модуля `Vcl.Graphics`, а в описании - из `Winapi.Windows`. На что и ругается компилятор, но не уточняет почему.

Решения:

Перенести Uses `Winapi.Windows` в раздел `interface`. Причём расположить раньше, чем `Vcl.Graphics`, чтобы определение `TBitmap` использовалось именно из модуля `Vcl.Graphics`.

Либо явно указать, `TBitmap` какого модуля используется. Вот так:

```
procedure HorizontalReflection(Bitmap: Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap);
```

это, на мой вкус, лучшее решение

Comment: Вот это выражение *"перебирает модули, начиная с конца"* не верно. Модули включаются в порядке их объявления, но если во втором модуле встречается такой же тип, что и в первом, то тип считается переопределённым. И подключение модулей начинается с секции interface, а затем implementation, а не наоборот.

Comment: *"The order in which units appear in the uses clause determines the order of their initialization and affects the way identifiers are located by the compiler. If two units declare a variable, constant, type, procedure, or function with the same name, the compiler uses the one from the unit listed last in the uses clause. (To access the identifier from the other unit, you would have to add a qualifier: UnitName.Identifier.) "* [Unit References and the Uses Clause](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Programs_and_Units_(Delphi)#Unit_References_and_the_Uses_Clause)

Comment: Не умаляя корректности Вашего ответа, добавлю, что лишняя долбежка по клавиатуре не всегда здорово. В следующей редакции Delphi могут поменять название модуля на `Vcl.GraphUnit` и вуаля: `Vcl.Graphics` уже не будет работать. Почему бы не ставить *системные модули* всегда в разделе `interface` и не заморачиваться на пустом месте? А где ну очень важно - там явно указывать тип данных. Полагаю, что VCL-ный битмап Вы используете в своей разработке чаще, чем Win-запись.

Comment: @zed Действительно, об этом я не подумал :) Посчитал, что как в фортране, FORTH'е и старом паскале парсер обрабатывает подключаемые ресурсы, начиная с конца. Исправлю.

Comment: @Dima Не соглашусь: исправить название подключаемого модуля - 5 секунд. А разбираться с кросс-референсами (пусть и в случае использования системных модулей они маловероятны), если они случаются - геморрой.